# Problem with my counter increment on addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am encountering a problem which I don't know how to solve it...

Here it's : (JavaScript)

```
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  data () {
    return  {
      titre: "",
      contenu: null,
      isDone: true,
      count : 0,
      nocount : 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let td1 = document.createElement("td");
    let td2 = document.createElement("td");
    let td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.textContent = this.titre;
    td2.textContent = this.contenu;
    td3.textContent = this.isDone ? "✓" : "❌";

      td3.addEventListener('click',function (){
        this.count++; //my problem is on this part, my counter doesn't increment
        this.nocount--; //here, this doesn't work too
        td3.textContent = this.isDone ? "❌" : "✓"; //this works
        })


    if(this.isDone) {this.count++} //this works and increments
    else{this.nocount++} // this also

      tr.append(td1, td2, td3);
    this.$refs.tableau.appendChild(tr);}
  },
  computed: {

      countDone : function ()  {
        return this.count;
      },

      countUnDone: function () {
        return this.nocount;
      }

    }}
</script>
```

(HTML)

```
<template>
  <div id="todolist">
      <h1> TodoList </h1>

    <p> {{count}} </p>
    <p> {{nocount}} </p>
  <form>
    <h2> Ajouter un élément</h2>
    <h5> Titre </h5>
    <input type="text" v-model="titre">
    <h5> Description </h5>
    <input type="text" v-model="contenu">
    <br>
    <label for="isDone"> Tâche déjà réalisée ? </label> <input type="checkbox" id="isDone" v-model="isDone">
    <br>
    <button type="button" @click="add"> Ajouter </button>
  </form>

  <h2> Liste </h2>
  <table> <thead> <tr> <th> Titre </th> <th> Description </th> <th> Etat </th> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody ref="tableau" id="tableau"> </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</template>
```

Picture :

[Click on the cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4MRs.png)
When I click to the cross, normally my counter of tick will increase and my counter of cross will decrease but unfortunately, nothing event is happen.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks you

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is to use arrow function instead of a anonymous function when you add the event listener, since the anonymous function have  a separate context from the function they are used in, so they do not have the vue instance attributes, arrow dunctions solve this issue.

So, use this:

td3.addEventListener('click',  () => {